# Laravel 5 | Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-localization

I use Laravel 5.

I try,

```
 "use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;"
```

to implement "Middleware" as,

```
class Language implements Middleware {
       // Some Functions 
  }
```

I Get Error as,

```
Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware' not found
```

Is actually that interface is Missing ?

(OR) Mistake in defining ?

(OR) Need to Create | Download ?

Thank Q !

Comment: did you put the correct namespace on top of the file " namespace App\Http\Middleware; " ?

Comment: Yep...Actually i create threw "php artisan"...
So every thing fine..

This Middleware not found exception only i get...

Comment: can you please share the full class code?

Comment: Sure...See at Answer portion...

Comment: Did you upgrade your Laravel 5.1 version to 5.2 ?

Comment: This is the Latest Version...(5.2)

Comment: I meant  If you upgrade 5.1 to 5.2 that may be cause for your problem. you can try to composer update

Comment: Yep...Update also Done....Nothing changed....Same Error....

Answer (score 6):

The Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware contract has been deprecated in 5.2, remove it. And dont use it in class definition.

Like this

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Applicaion;

class Language{
    //..... YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: I see the changes since 5.2. Still i get this error `Interface 'App\Http\Middleware\Middleware' not found`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you realy placed those double quote, but here is a working example:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class Language implements Middleware {
   // Some Functions 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Class :

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

```
use Closure;

use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class Language implements Middleware {

public function __construct(Application $app, Redirector $redirector, Request $request) {
    $this->app = $app;
    $this->redirector = $redirector;
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Closure $next, $request)
{
    // Make sure current locale exists.
    $locale = $request->segment(1);

    if ( ! array_key_exists($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.locales'))) {
        $segments = $request->segments();
        $segments[0] = $this->app->config->get('app.fallback_locale');

        return $this->redirector->to(implode('/', $segments));
    }

    $this->app->setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}

 }
```

**LOC :** App/Http/Middleware/Language.php