# how to create middleware in octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, octobercms

I'm new to **OctoberCMS** but I have moderate knowledge about **Laravel**.

In Laravel it is easy to create middleware and group more than one middleware.

In OctoberCMS I can't find proper guidelines or a satisfactory answer yet.

Does anyone know how to create middleware and group more then one middleware in OctoberCMS ?

Comment: Here is link may be this can help you https://octobercms.com/forum/post/how-to-enable-cors

Comment: @DCoder can't find much useful but thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your plugin folder, use the file Plugin.php to set up your middleware
You must declare in boot function like this :

```
  public function boot()
  {
    // Register middleware
     $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']
          ->pushMiddleware('Experty\Experts\Middleware\ExpertsMiddleware');
  }
```

and in ExpertsMiddleware.php

```
<?php namespace Experty\Experts\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use October\Rain\Exception\AjaxException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class ExpertsMiddleware implements Middleware
{
/**
     * The Laravel Application
     *
     * @var Application
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  Application $app
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }
 /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      //youre code
     }
}
```

Comment: _"The Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware contract has been deprecated in Laravel 5.2"_ https://stackoverflow.com/a/35487715/69537

Comment: i'm getting an error: 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class path.storage does not exist in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/israplanet.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:752